# Return a message if nothing is found after filtering an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm getting an array in React/Next, but before mapping through it I'm running a few filters and sorting it. I'd like to display a simple message if nothing gets found after the filters run. It should display a span with a simple text string (jsx).

The code is pretty simple:

```
{ArrayObj
            .filter(
              (item) =>
                // conditions here
            )
            .sort((a, b) => (a.condition > b.condition ? 1 : -1))
            .map((item) => (
              <li key={item._id}>
                // contents of each iteration here
              </li>
))}
```

I'm guessing it should go just right before the .map but I'm stuck at this.

The full code is as follows:

```
{yachtListings
            .filter(
              (yacht) =>
                yacht.buildYear >= searchYear &&
                yacht.price <= searchPrice &&
                yacht.length <= searchLength &&
                yacht.type === searchType
            )
            .filter((yacht) =>
              filterKeyword == ''
                ? yacht
                : yacht.modelName
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(filterKeyword.toLowerCase())
            )
            .sort((a, b) => (a[sortOrder] > b[sortOrder] ? 1 : -1))
            .map((yacht) => (
              <li key={yacht._id}>
                <SecondHandCard />  // card components with props
              </li>
            ))}
```

You can see a live demo [here](https://magnayachts.netlify.app/en/second-hands). I'm a front-end guy taking my skills to the back-end more and more.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the array first and then conditionally show jsx depending on the length of that.

```
let filteredArray = ArrayObj.filter((item) => {...}).sort(...);
{filteredArray.length == 0 ? <span>Message</span> : filteredArray.map(...)}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'll try to implement your solution. I added a link to a demo in the original post.